# Is there any way to attach a file without the FileUpload?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, file-upload

I encrypted a pdf and would like to save it to the database, below are the codes as to how I did it. I would like to know if there are any ways to set the Created "PDFEncrypted.pdf" onto the Stream fs without using a FileUploader?

```
     string WorkingFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        string InputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "PDF.pdf");
        string OutputFile = Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, "PDFEncrypted.pdf");

        using (Stream input = new FileStream(InputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (Stream output = new FileStream(OutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(InputFile);
              PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(reader, output, true, "pass123", "secret", PdfWriter.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS);
            }
        }
```

So I have these codes to upload it

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```